# Mongodb array of elements have to group based on same elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Am having "Orders" collection and "Order_Items" is an array inside "Orders" collection.

"Order_Item" (array) have the following elements :

```
  {
  "line_number": "611194",
  "split_number": "1",
  },
    {
  "line_number": "611194",
  "split_number": "1",
  },
    {
  "line_number": "611194",
  "split_number": "2",
  },
    {
  "line_number": "611194",
  "split_number": "3",
  },
    {
  "line_number": "611194",
  "split_number": "3",
  },
```

So, i have to create a separate "Orders" for the common Split_Number  like :

Order id : 1

```
   {
    "line_number": "611194",
    "split_number": "1",
   },
   {
    "line_number": "611194",
    "split_number": "1",
   },
```

Order id : 2

```
{
  "line_number": "611194",
  "split_number": "2",
},
```

Order id : 3

```
{
   "line_number": "611194",
   "split_number": "3",
},
{
  "line_number": "611194",
  "split_number": "3",
},
```

Following code am using :

```
    var result = lines.reduce((p, c) => {
          const key = `Order_Items_${c}`;
          p[key] = p[key] || [];
          p[key].push(c)
          return p;
        }, {});
```

Comment: Your third example is kind of confusing:  shouldn't both split numbers be 3?

Comment: Nope., its typo error.., now its corrected., it should be 3..

Comment: for your information....am using reactjs

Comment: Do you have control of the mongo query?

Comment: yes., am using "this.setState ({item:item})" for inserting collections in mongodb. in this scenario., i dont know how i can setState.

Comment: this.setState({ item: item })
    this.props.create(this.state.item);  .... In this way., am creating new document in "Orders" collection. In this situation., i dont know where i can set the state for item to be store in mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer:  It's tough to understand exactly what you're asking, but I think this answer provides the essence of what you are trying to accomplish.

You could achieve this using the mongo Aggregation framework like this:

```
db.getCollection('OrderItems').aggregate([{ $group: 
    {
        _id: "$split_number",
        line_numbers: { $push:  "$line_number"  }
    }
}])
```

This will return to you all orders and group by the split_number.  Then provide you a collection of line numbers that link to that split_number.

Comment: am trying in another way with the help of for loop. that may help you to understand my situation better. wait

Comment: handleAutoSplit(e) {
  var item = this.state.item;
  var lines = item.order_items;
  for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) 
  {
   for ( var k=0; k < lines.length; k++)
    {
     if (lines[j].split_number == lines[k].split_number) 
      {
      
      var line = { line_id: uuidv4(), split_number:lines[k].split_number, product_quantity:lines[k].product_quantity };
      console.log("Split Number::::"+lines[k].split_number);
      
      }
     item.order_items.push(line);
    }
    this.setState({ item: item })
    this.props.create(this.state.item);
  }